# How to read large csv data into memory with BufferedReader?

Tags: java, csv, large-data

This is how I read the data:

```
List<String[]> res = new ArrayList<>();

S3Object object = s3.getObject(s3BucketName, path);
InputStream inputStream = object.getObjectContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    res.add(line.split(","));
}
reader.close();
```

It will throw OutOfMemory Exception after I read 10M rows.

I have tried to use -Xms=20G -Xmx=20G as parameters, the weird thing is when I changed it to -Xms=2m -Xmx=2m, both results are the same, they can only read 10M rows. My method is to put it into Intellij program parameters box.

I expect to find a way to read all the rows into memory. My file is 16M rows x 16 column which is only 1G size, so 20G should be fine.

Comment: Do you have 20G? Are you adding the -Xmx as a VM argument or as aprogram arguments? Are there additional commas. I could see a 1G file taking up more space after reading and splitting it but not 20G.

Comment: In your 1GB calculation you apparently assume each cell is 4 bytes - but you are processing character data so a cell like `1000000000` occupies 20 bytes (a java char takes 2 bytes) + overhead of string and list.  This may just be a minor note but worth considering in your calculations.

Comment: You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` to see if your `-Xmx` is going through at all

Answer (score -1):

> My method is to put it into Intellij program parameters box.

If you use IntelliJ to run your program then the memory limits configured for IntelliJ will limit your program as well. Try to run it standalone from command line to get better results.